# Comment rendre « meaningful expressions » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, synonymes

> State which of the following expressions are meaningful in the indicial notation.

> Indiquer quelles formules parmi les suivantes ont du sens dans la notation indicielle.

Je me demande s'il existe une autre façon d'exprimer *meaningful*, au sens de « a mathematical expression that has a meaning ».

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101795/discussion-on-question-by-dimitris-comment-rendre--meaningful-expressions-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voici ce que j'écrirais :

> Quelles formules parmi les suivantes ont **un** sens **en** notation indicielle.